# Python recursive quadtree issues

Tags: python, numpy, quadtree

I've been writing a recursive quadtree constructor to use for some n-body simulations, but my current implementation doesn't seem to be working properly, and after a lot of debugging, I'm stumped. The results that it gives are clearly incorrect, although all the debugging checks seem to give the results they should. Could anyone help?
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numba import jit, autojit
import matplotlib.animation as ani
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from time import sleep

mu, sigma = 0, 0.5
size = 50
X = np.array([np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size),np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size)])
A = np.zeros([size,2],dtype='float64')
V = np.zeros([size,2],dtype='float64')
M = np.random.normal(1, 0, size)

quad_list = np.zeros([4,1])
def quadtree(p,n,x,y,w,h):
    global quad_list
    L = len(p[0])
    if L>1:
        print(len(p[0]))
        midx = (w/2+x)
        midy = (h/2+y)
        px = p[0]
        py = p[1]
        plx, ply = px[px<midx], py[px<midx]
        prx, pry = px[px>midx], py[px>midx]
        p1 = np.array([plx[ply>midy],ply[ply>midy]])
        p2 = np.array([prx[pry>midy],pry[pry>midy]])
        p3 = np.array([prx[pry<midy],pry[pry<midy]])
        p4 = np.array([plx[ply<midy],ply[ply<midy]])
        quad_list = np.append(quad_list,np.array([x,y,w,h]))
        quadtree(p1,n+1,x,y+h/2,w/2,h/2)
        quadtree(p2,n+1,x+w/2,y+h/2,w/2,h/2)
        quadtree(p3,n+1,x,y,w/2,h/2)
        quadtree(p4,n+1,x,y,w/2,h/2)
    else:
        quad_list = np.append(quad_list,np.array([x,y,w,h]))
quadtree(X,0,-2,-2,4,4)
plt.scatter(X[0],X[1],c='black')
out = np.zeros([4,int(len(quad_list)/4)])
for i in range(0,int(len(quad_list)),4):
    for j in range(4):
        out[j,int(i/4)] = quad_list[i+j]
for n in range(int(len(out[0,:]))):
    print(n)
    plt.plot([out[0,n],out[0,n]], [out[1,n],out[1,n]+out[3,n]])
    plt.plot([out[0,n]+out[2,n],out[0,n]+out[2,n]], [out[1,n],out[1,n]+out[3,n]])
    plt.plot([out[0,n],out[0,n]+out[2,n]], [out[1,n],out[1,n]])
    plt.plot([out[0,n],out[0,n]+out[2,n]], [out[1,n]+out[3,n],out[1,n]+out[3,n]])
plt.show()
```

Thank in advance!
(Footnote: I'm making a more optimised version where `quad_list` is a list)

Comment: Can you please explain why the results are incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure as to *why* they're incorrect, only that some points aren't separated by a boundary, and there are some pointless squares which enclose nothing at all, almost as if it has split the area up randomly @Patol75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line:

```
quadtree(p3,n+1,x,y,w/2,h/2)
```

to

```
quadtree(p3,n+1,x+w/2,y,w/2,h/2)
```